# Making to slide more than one item ahead in OwlCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I having two synced OwlCarousel sliders. The goal is to achieve - group of items sliding in first main slider. Now it's sliding from 1 to 2 to 3 etc. I need it to slide from 1 to 5. Is there some values i can change in js?
https://codepen.io/washaweb/pen/KVRxRW

```
 .owlCarousel({
items : slidesPerPage,
dots: false,
nav: false,
autoplay: false,
smartSpeed: 200,
slideSpeed : 500,
mouseDrag: false,
touchDrag: false,
pullDrag: false,
slideBy: '1', //alternatively you can slide by 1, this way the active slide will stick to the first item in the second carousel
responsiveRefreshRate : 100
```

And how can i change sliding animation? For example fadein

Answer (score 1):

You could try **to.owl.carousel** event:

```
var jumpTo = 5;
$('#sync2').trigger('to.owl.carousel', jumpTo);
```

Carousel #sync2 jumps to slide number 5. You can trigger this by other owl events or by clicks.

Comment: Yeah, that worked! Thanks. But for example, how can i do this with 4-5 pages of slides? Goal is slide to 5-8-11 etc. I mean how can i get position of slider?